# jump to specific function declaration from command line in Notepad++

Tags: command-line, notepad++

With Notepad++ it is possible to jump into a source file at a certain line number using the option "-n" together with the target filename. Now, I'd like to start Notepad++ from the command line and directly jump to a certain function definition block, e.g. by specifying a certain text string on the command line. Thus realizing direct links to a block of soure code whose starting line number might change frequently. Would this be possible somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Try to find out the line number first, and passing that as an argument to Notepad++.

set results=find /n "string we are looking for" C:\path-to-file.txt

/n adds the line number at the beginning in your results

findstr may be helpful to extract the line number after you used find:
echo %results%|findstr /R some_pattern

See also:

- https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/find.mspx?mfr=true
- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create a small script (Batch, Perl, whatever) that retrieve the line number and run Notepad++.

Here is an example with windows batch; to run it, you just need to do
`Notepad_jumpline.bat <filename> <section>`

```
@REM --Notepad_jumpline.bat--

@echo off

for /f "tokens=1" %%i in ('findstr /n %2 %1') do (
    set n_lines=%%i
    goto _Run_Notepad_
)

:_Run_Notepad_
set n_lines=%n_lines::=%
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" %1 -n%n_lines%
```